# Read and write during a SQLite transaction on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions

For my application, I'm developing a means to synchronize a local SQLite database with an external one. The algorithm I have in mind to do this relies on the ability to read and write to the database during a transaction. This would require that the database I'm working with would always reflect the latest state of the database, even prior to a commit. For instance, say I have the following table:

```
id  |   value
--------------
1   |   a
2   |   b
3   |   c
4   |   d
```

I start a transaction and delete the second row. My database should now look like this:

```
id  |   value
--------------
1   |   a
3   |   c
4   |   d
```

Then I query the database again to get every row. It should look like this:

```
id  |   value
--------------
1   |   a
3   |   c
4   |   d
```

But will it look like that, or will it look like the original table because the transaction has not been committed? I'm not totally clear on the behavior of SQLite during transactions, and I don't see anything specifically about this in the documentation. I hope I was clear with my question. Any questions, please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different transactions are isolated from each other, but a transaction is not isolated from itself.
In other words, a transaction always sees its own changes.